# nodejs: array method, filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to double the elements in an array using filter method.But the output is getting the same array itself only.Please suggest what is the correction part in my code.

This is my array elements :

```
[1,4,2,7,3,9,4,15]
```

Expected output :

```
[2,8,4,14,6,18,8,30]
```

what I tried :

```js
let arr = [1, 4, 2, 7, 3, 9, 4, 15];
function doubleArr(num) {
  return num * 2;
}
let result = arr.filter(doubleArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

As its name indicates the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is to filter elements from the array
 what you need here is to map through the array element using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return every element multiplied with 2

```js
let test = [1,4,2,7,3,9,4,15];
let result = test.map((element) => element*2)
```